# ZF2 authentication session is not working

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2

I am using ZF2 authentication. It writes the authentication credentials into the storage properly.
Also I can see my session variable being set (checked by print_r($_SESSION)).

My **doubts** are: 
**1.** the function, hasIdentity() from AuthenticationService.php always returns false even if the authentication is successful 
 As a result I can't log in.
In my config/autoload/global.php I have config like this:

```
'session' => array(
    'config' => array(
        'class' => 'Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig',
        'options' => array(
            'name' => 'testsuitestudio',
            'remember_me_seconds' => $lifeTime,
            'gc_maxlifetime'      => $lifeTime,
            'gc_divisor'          =>1,
            'gc_probability'      =>1,
            'cookie_lifetime'     =>$lifeTime,
            'cookie_domain'       => $subDomainVar,
            'cache_expire'        => $lifeTime,
            'save_path'           => $sessionDirectory

        ),
    ),
    'storage' => 'Zend\Session\Storage\SessionArrayStorage',
    'validators' => array(
        array(
            'Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr',
            'Zend\Session\Validator\HttpUserAgent',
        ),
    ),
),
```

**2.** If I comment out :'cookie_domain' => $subDomainVar, from the above array, it works fine.

What could be the issue?

Comment: we dont have any clue about what is the value of  $subDomainVar, and what is your current domain.

Comment: it's a string and holds 'test-project', which is the name of the domain